# Apache shows .html, .php files as .txt

Tags: apache-2.2, php, vps, html

I have files in public_html (index.html). When I go to the main page it gives me "Apache Test Page". When I try to add link to them manually (domain_name/index.html or index2.php) it gives me only code, like in .txt editor. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: is it showing correctly formatted html files as text? (because that would suggest some other mime-type problem, i.e. apache is sending html files as text/plain)

Comment: Please specify the operating system you're using, as well as the version of PHP currently installed. Quite likely this is simply a matter of mod_php not being installed or correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to ensure that the php is installed correctly. See the output of `apachectl -M` and look for `php5_module (shared)`:

```
# apachectl -M
 ...
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 ... 
 php5_module (shared)   <---here, need this
 dav_svn_module (shared)
 authz_svn_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

This last step is generally achieved by installing the `php` package, which contains support for configuring php module in httpd automatically.

Then check that php-script is configured as the php interpreter is used for scripts with the php suffix;

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
  LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

on centos these directives show up in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` and restart apache2.

Comment: When I write in command shell: apachectl -M. It gives me that:
httpd: Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory.
           
57 line: ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
             
221 line: Include conf.d/*.conf

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like that your apache installation is configured to load mime module.

Please run

```
# apachectl -M | grep mime
```

and check if you can see any mime module in the list.
If not, then install the mime module. Please have a look at this,
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html

Generally apache ships with mime module and you may not need to recompile it.